# For every column in a sheet search for a value in a cell, then select that column and insert a column before that one

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to write a macro that performed the following:

For every sheet in the workbook:
1. Select a column 
2. Search in the selected column for a specific value in the Row number 5 
3. If that value matches another cel (A1), then Insert two columns before the selected column

1. Perform the same for every column in the sheet. (i mean, those columns where there is something, I know that there are an infinite amount of potential columns).

Any help or direction toward an answer would be more than helpful.

Comment: this macro is very feasible to write, but you will get a lot more help if you edit your question and let us know what you tried and / or what is not working with what you tried

Comment: Thats the thing. Im pretty new to vba, I thought of writing a For with an index for the columns, then if the 5th row in the indexed column matches, select the whole Column, and Insert two columns. The problem is Im not sure how IFs  and Fors work in vba, and how to do that for every column.

My apologies if Im not explaining myself, Im pretty new to vba and its being harder than I thought.

Comment: For's and If's work the same in VBA as many other languages. It's also very easy to google VBA For loop or VBA to see how they work. Anyway, see answer below. Let me know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you what you are after, I think.

```
Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wks
        Dim intCol As Integer, intCnt As Integer

        intCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For intCnt = intCol To 2 Step -1 'assumes you ignore col A since your match value is there
            If .Cells(5, intCnt) = .Cells(1, 1) Then
                .Range(.Cells(1, intCnt), .Cells(1, intCnt + 1)).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        Next

    End With

Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Im gonna try it!