# Replace cells containing "#VALUE!" with average value of surrounding cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns of data with some cells containing `#VALUE!`. Annoying ofcourse, so I would like to write a macro which would replace these `#VALUE!` cells in each worksheet with the average value of 2 cells both above and below.

Eg.

```
    A               A
1   1               1
2   2               2
3  #VALUE!    ->    3
4   4               4
5   5               5
```

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504741/copy-and-insert-rows-based-off-of-values-in-a-column) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658336/for-every-column-in-a-sheet-search-for-a-value-in-a-cell-then-select-that-colum) and have the following code but being a beginner, I am clearly missing something as I receive a "run-time error '13'".

```
Sub Test()

Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wks
        Dim Qty As Range

        For Each Qty In Range("A:ZZ").Cells

            If InStr(1, (Qty.Value), "#VALUE!") Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-2]C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[2]C)"
            Range("A:ZZ").Select

            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `#Value!` usually denotes a formula error in the cell.  Were these values copied and pasted as "VALUES" into this column or is there a formula in Cell `A3`?

Comment: @xQbert - Ahh that makes sense with the formula error, thank you. The values were copied/pasted as "VALUES".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
If InStr(1, (Qty.Text), "#VALUE!") Then
```

and since **Qty** is a *Range*, don't use *ActiveCell;* instead:

```
Qty.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-2]C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[2]C)"
```

**EDIT#2:**

Here is some working code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, Qty As Range

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wks
            For Each Qty In Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:ZZ").Cells)
                If InStr(1, (Qty.Text), "#VALUE!") Then
                    Qty.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-2]C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[2]C)"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next wks
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this has resolved the issue as the macro is running. Doing some testing then will report back.

Comment: The macro ran but no changes were made, the cells still contain "#VALUE!".

Comment: I would drop the string comparison and check directly whether the value is a cell error. `If IsError(Qty.Value)` which can then be followed up by `If Qty.Value = CVErr(xlErrValue` to test specifically for `#VALUE!` if necessary. Note that the string comparison will fail if for some reason the cell contains the text `#VALUE! is my favorite error!` :-)

Comment: Many thanks for your working code, this is much better and neater than what I had!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - That's a brilliant tip, thank you. I will try and incorporate that and see how it goes!